# Non campaign days: Interview question Amazon

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Recently an interview question was asked in Amazon.

There is a table `Sheet1$`:

```
Campaign_ID   Start_date     End_Date
1             2021-01-01     2021-01-04
2             2021-01-10     2021-01-25    
3             2021-02-03     2021-02-13
```

I want to find out the non campaign days in Jan and Feb 2021 from this table.

Attempt

```
declare @startdate Date
set @startdate='2021-01-01'
declare @enddate Date
set @enddate='2021-02-28'

select [Start date ], [End date]
from dbo.Sheet1$
where [Start date ] >=@startdate
and [end date] <= @enddate and year([Start date ]) = '2021' and year([End date]) = '2021' and month([Start date])
```

(database only has Jan and Feb data as of now).

There is no error but I am not getting correct answer. I am getting all dates between start and end date. I need the dates when campaign was not active. So here non campaign days will be 5 Jan - 9 Jan, 26 Jan to 2 Feb and 14 Feb to 28 Feb. I am not getting desired result

Comment: This is something that would benefit from a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6844/sql-server-calendar-table-example/)

Comment: Hi added my attempt

Comment: *I am getting error Must declare the scalar variable "@startdate".* - that's because you haven't declared it. declare `@startdate date='20210101'`

Comment: Why are you comparing integers (`year(End date])` to strings (`'2021'`) rather than integers (`2021`)? What does `and month([Start date])` mean since `and` usually involves a `boolean` or performs a bitwise operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by creating a date table with all the days from Jan and Feb. Then its quite a simple left join. Here is a sample script.

```
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE Campaign 
(
    Campaing_ID INT,
    Start_Date DATE,
    End_Date DATE
);

INSERT INTO Campaign
VALUES
    (1, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-04'),
    (2, '2021-01-10', '2021-01-25'),   
    (3, '2021-02-03', '2021-02-13')

SELECT * FROM Campaign;

DECLARE 
    @StartDate date = '2021-1-1',
    @EndDate date = '2021-2-28';

WITH DatesTable AS (
    SELECT 
        @StartDate d
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(day, 1, d)
    FROM 
        DatesTable
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(day, 1, d) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT
    DatesTable.d Non_Campaign_Day
FROM
    DatesTable
    LEFT JOIN Campaign 
        ON DatesTable.d BETWEEN Campaign.Start_Date AND Campaign.End_Date
WHERE
    Campaign.Start_Date IS NULL

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: wont  a left join include all common rows too? (onces where campaign was run basically)

Comment: Yes. If the date is between the start and end of one of the campaigns the Start_Date will be a date and not be null. So to exclude those the where clause only includes the rows that have a NULL Start_Date.